# Request parameter not received in spring mvc using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm not able to send a parameter using Ajax jquery to my spring class. Here is the code .

```
package com.controller;




@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);

/*@Autowired
EmployeeImpl employee;*/

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method =  {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET}) 
public @ResponseBody String ajaxJsonRequest(@RequestParam("firstname") String firstname) 
{

    System.out.println("***** TEST METHOD *****");
    System.out.println(firstname);
    return "Hello "+firstname;
}    
}
```

### My Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/SpringProject/hello",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("fail");
        }
});
```

### Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SpringProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>   
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/lib/soapservice-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param> -->

<!--    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
 -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <servlet- class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Error which I'm getting is

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/hello Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I suppose that there should be problem in the config part of putting the URl...

Answer (score 0):

Use servlet mapping as mentioned below. This will cause all urls to be served by Spring Dispatcher servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried.. When I put that, the startup jsp itself is not opening

Comment: Take a look at Spring showcase [Showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your ajax request and your controller implementation. Your Controoler expects a firstName parameter which is mandatory. However your ajax request has a request body without request parameters.

Either change your ajax request so that it sends a firstname paramater as follows

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/SpringProject/hello?firstname=" + firstnameVal,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("fail");
        }
});
```

Or change your controller so that it accepts a request body mapped object. For example assuming your data represents a User object

```
public class User{

   private String firstname;

   //getters and setters

}
```

Your controller becomes

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method =  {RequestMethod.POST}) 
public @ResponseBody String ajaxJsonRequest(@RequestBody User user) 
{

    System.out.println("***** TEST METHOD *****");
    System.out.println(user.getFirstname());
    return "Hello "+user.getFirstName();
}
```

In this case your data in the ajax request will be converted to a User object using configure HttpMessageConverter in this case MappingJackson2MessageConverter

Also change your servlet mapping as follows

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```